# How to auto-accept cookies notifications as mandated by EU law?

Tags: safari, plugins, cookies

EU law forces websites to notify visitors about the use of cookies. Clicking on these messages is quite a nuisance. I've found a plugin on  http://web.archive.org/web/20191214230044/http://cookiesok.com but this is only available for Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Does anybody know of something similar for Safari? Or other means to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Use an AdBlock Filter

Filter the cookie requests using your preferred [advert blocker](https://adblockplus.org) for Safari and the [block-the-eu-cookie-s***-list](https://github.com/r4vi/block-the-eu-cookie-shit-list):

> Adblock / Adblock plus filter list for blocking cookie notifications
>
> Add https://raw.github.com/r4vi/block-the-eu-cookie-shit-list/master/filterlist.txt to your filter subscriptions if you want to block "EU cookie law" notifications and popups.

Please note the swear word in the link is required. Regrettable, as the name will limit widespread adoption.

Comment: Unfortunately, a simple blocking filter doesn't work for cookie alerts that require clicking 'yes' before cookies are set :(

Comment: For sites that demand acceptance, an exception to the advert blocker can be added. This is often called whitelisting a site. This can be done on a site by site basis.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't auto-acceptance like the extension in the question.

Comment: After dealing with this EU forces notifications about cookies for years now: I think the swear word in the link is very reasonable.

Answer (score 12):

For iOS Safari, Adguard with “I don’t care about cookies” filter works pretty well.
[image]

Comment: That's very interesting, could you add a screenshot of the setting to your answer?

Comment: Thanks! The same filters exist on AdGuard for OS X and works perfectly. All the cookie notifications stop appearing in Safari.

Comment: This is also like the accepted answer in that it is not auto-acceptance but rather just hides the cookie prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a Safari specific browser extension to do just that called [Hush](https://oblador.github.io/hush/). Since it uses the Content Blocker API it can only block scripts and hide elements, but can't click on accept/reject buttons for sites that force you do so before continuing. That means it can't block some popular sites like Google and Instagram, but on the other hand makes it work with iOS.

It's free, fast, open source and can't access your browser history/passwords.

Comment: This is also like the accepted answer in that it is not auto-acceptance but rather just hides the cookie prompt.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks for this oblador!

Comment: Read the other comment @MarcosCurvello

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I've found a solution, but *it requires access to view history*, tho   *developer says, that he does not sell any data* and the only data he gets is your account email to enable sync across different devices(useless, but optional feature). The account creation is also optional. If anyone can prove its privacy claims, I'd be glad, because I hardly believe him as the **extension is FREE**.

It's called "*Super Agent*" and **here's the link**: https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/super-agent-for-safari/id1568262835?l=en

This extension automatically selects the cookie settings you want. That means that you won't see any more popups and your privacy should be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Stand alone extension (without ad blocking features):

https://smartersoft.github.io/CookiebarGone/

Comment: The extensions seems not to be maintained anymore; the last update is from 2016.